# what happend with my cron job?

Tags: magento-1.9, error

I created a new cron job to change the status of expired orders, but I can not make it work. I have tried to upload it in System> scheduler> Job configuration. But the following error always comes out

**Invalid callback: Method for sales/observer::cancelUnprocessedOrders does not exist**

Model: *sales/observer*

```
public function cancelUnprocessedOrders($schedule)
{                 
  $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT))
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
  $orders ="";
    foreach($orderCollection->getItems() as $order)
        {
          $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
          $orderModel->load($order['entity_id']);


          if(!$orderModel->canCancel())
          continue;

          $orderModel->cancel();
          $orderModel->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
          $orderModel->save(); 
    }
}
```

config.xml

```
<cancelorder_cron>
  <schedule>
    <cron_expr>0 2 */2 * *</cron_expr>
  </schedule>
  <run>
    <model>sales/observer::cancelUnprocessedOrders</model>
  </run>
</cancelorder_cron>
```

I'm using another cron job as a reference, even using the same model and still I can not make it work.

**Update**

Can someone tell me if my script is wrong?

Comment: Are you overriding a core class or creating a custom model? What is the class name of the method cancelUnprocessedOrders?

Comment: No, I added my code in this class. The class name is `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer` , but when I try to do it this way, the model is not recognized.

Comment: The core file may have been overriden in some other module. You can check it by placing some "die('using original file');" at the beginning of the file - if you don't see it, look for "extends Mage_Sales_Model_Observer" in community/local modules or check XML files to find what's overriding it.

Comment: Good idea, I will test it.